# How to remove JSON tags which are not configured?

Tags: java, json

I want to update the JSON structure only based on the fields we have specified in the property file.

e.g. I have sample JSON as :

```
    {"Accounts": [{
        "AccountId": "aaa",
        "Currency": "xxx",
        "Account": {
            "SchemeName": "BBAN",
            "Identification": "10203345",
            "Name": "Lorem"
            },
        "Servicer": {
            "SchemeName": "hhss",
            "Identification": "SC802001"
        },
        "links": {
            "self": "/accounts/aaa",
            "related": "/accounts"
        }
        }],
        "links": {
            "self": "/accounts"
    }
   }
```

In the propery file we have specified

```
Accounts
Accounts/AccountId
Accounts/Currency
Accounts/Nickname
Accounts/links
links
```

Now I want to remove all other tags which are not specified in the property file.

Can some one help me to know how can we do this in JAVA ?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I have find the solution to remove the code which are not needed, but here i want the elements only specified in property file and i have not found any solution or option.

Comment: Your json is incorrect. You can check it using JSONLint. Here is link https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: corrected the json..